# ipydatagrid widget does not display in SageMaker Studio

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

### The problem

I have a jupyter notebook with an `ipydatagrid` widget that displays a dataframe. This notebook works correctly when run locally, but not when run in AWS SageMaker Studio. When run in SageMaker Studio, instead of showing the widget it simply shows the text `Loading widget...`

How does one use a `ipydatagrid` widget in the SageMaker Studio environment?

### Details

Python version:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.7.10
```

Run at start:

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
$ jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix widgetsnbextension
$ jupyter nbextension install --py --symlink --sys-prefix ipydatagrid
$ jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix ipydatagrid
```

File `requirements.txt`:

```
ipydatagrid==1.1.11
pandas==1.0.1
```

Notebook contents:

```py
# %%
import pandas as pd
from ipydatagrid import DataGrid
from IPython.display import display
import ipywidgets

# %%
data = [
    ("potato", 1.2, True),
    ("sweet potato", 0.8, False),
    ("french fries", 4.5, True),
    ("waffle fries", 4.9, True)
]
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data,
    columns=["food", "stars", "is_available"]
)

# %%
grid = DataGrid(df)

# %%
display(grid)

# %%
# SANITY CHECK:
button = ipywidgets.Button(
    description="Button",
    disabled=False
)
def on_click(b):
    print("CLICK")
button.on_click(on_click)
display(button)
```

#### Error messages

If I use the Google Chrome developer tools, I can see more logs in the browser that give some error messages, most of which are repeated:

```
manager.js:305 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Module ipydatagrid, semver range ^1.1.11 is not registered as a widget module
    at C.loadClass (manager.js:305:19)
    at C.<anonymous> (manager-base.js:263:46)
    at l (manager-base.js:44:23)
    at Object.next (manager-base.js:25:53)
    at manager-base.js:19:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Rtm6.k (manager-base.js:15:12)
    at C.e._make_model (manager-base.js:257:16)
    at C.<anonymous> (manager-base.js:246:45)
    at l (manager-base.js:44:23)
```

```
utils.js:119 Error: Could not create a model.
    at n (utils.js:119:27)
    at async C._handleCommOpen (manager.js:61:51)
    at async v._handleCommOpen (default.js:994:100)
    at async v._handleMessage (default.js:1100:43)
```

```
manager-base.js:273 Could not instantiate widget
```

However, there is no overt error message that's immediately obvious to the user, including in the log where `print` statements send their output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SageMaker Studio currently runs JupyterLab v1.2 (as confirmed by *Help > About JupyterLab*), and per the [ipydatagrid installation instructions](https://github.com/bloomberg/ipydatagrid#Installation), current/recent versions of this widget require v3+... So I think this is most likely your problem - as there were breaking changes in the interfaces for extensions between these major versions.

I had a quick look at the past releases of `ipydatagrid` to see if using an older version would be possible, and it seems like the documented JLv3 requirement gets added between [v0.2.16](https://github.com/bloomberg/ipydatagrid/tree/0.2.16) and [v1.0.1](https://github.com/bloomberg/ipydatagrid/tree/1.0.1) (which are adjacent on GitHub).

However, the old install instructions documented on 0.2 don't seem to work anymore: I get `ValueError: "jupyter-datagrid" is not a valid npm package` and also note that versions <1.0 don't seem to be present [on PyPI](https://libraries.io/pypi/ipydatagrid/versions).

So unfortunately I think (unless/until SM Studio gets a JupyterLab version upgrade), this widget's not likely to work unless you dive in to building it from an old source code version.